# Trying to format a number to a percentage

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to figure out how to convert the number that is displayed in the textbox as a percentage.

My program is basically calculating the percent change for cars sold in 2016 and 2017.

To test it out I did cars sold in 2016 = 7 and cars sold in 2017 = 12 and I got a really long number. I know that you use (“p”) or (“P”) to format the number but I just can’t figure out where to put it?

```
private void calcbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double carsIn2016; //  number of cars sold in 2016
    double carsIn2017; // number of cars sold in 2017
    double Percentchanged; // calculate the % change

    carsIn2016 = double.Parse(soldIn2016txtbox.Text); //get input from text box
    carsIn2017 = double.Parse(soldIn2017txtbox.Text);  // get input from text box 
    Percentchanged =(carsIn2017 - carsIn2016) / (carsIn2016 * 100); // calculate the % change 

    MessageBox.Show( "Your total % change is   " + Percentchanged);
}
```

Comment: I believe that it would be `string.Format("Your total % change is {0:P}", Percentchanged)` or something? I don't use winforms, so it could be that they have some other way to do it.

Comment: @MattRollins That doesn't depend on winforms, it's built into the core framework

Answer (score 2):

> Precentage Difference:  Work out the difference (increase) between the two numbers you are comparing. Then: divide the increase by the original number and multiply the answer by 100

Since you are calculating precent before printing. If you use formatter then  you will get bad result. You just need a number for string formatter, to convert it to precent. Dont multiply by 100 and use formatter.

You actually have the precent in `PrecentChanged` variable.

```
double carsIn2016; //  number of cars sold in 2016
double carsIn2017; // number of cars sold in 2017
double Percentchanged; // calculate the % change

carsIn2016 = double.Parse("7"); //get input from text box
carsIn2017 = double.Parse("12");  // get input from text box 
Percentchanged =((carsIn2017 - carsIn2016) / (carsIn2016));//* 100); // calculate the % change 



var output = String.Format("Your total % change is : {0:P}.", Percentchanged);
```

**Output**
71.43%

If you multiply by 100 and then use formatter

**Output**
Value: 7,142.86%.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is ToString(), which can be used with the "P" that you indicate.

```
MessageBox.Show("Your total % change is " + PercentChanged.ToString("P"));
```

You can also do various other formatting via ToString, as indicated on [Microsoft's Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: When I did the ToString and the ("P"), it says  "PercentChanged does not exist in the current context". Did  I declare it wrong or something?

Comment: aw nvm I just had an uppercase letter in there. Thank you for your help!